# PHP MySQL How can I paginate within two while loop

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, while-loop

I would like to know how can I do a LIMIT 0,10 in this case (in order to do a pagination later) because when I do this I obtain a total of 30 results (10 results for each result of the first loop) which is logical, any idea ?

```
$select = "SELECT X FROM Y"

$result = mysql_query($select,$link);

$total = mysql_num_rows($result);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

  $Name = $row['X'];
  $select2 = "SELECT id FROM `".$Name."` LIMIT 0,30 ";
  $result2 = mysql_query($select2,$link) or die ('Erreur : '.mysql_error() );
  $total2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);

  while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { 
     echo $row2['id']
  } 
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: even you can join two table so no need to use two while loop

Comment: no no I can't do joints there's no keys , otherwise it would be too easy

Comment: @Dipesh do you have an other idea ?

Comment: let me know what do you need..?  what are you trying to archive.?

Comment: I need to extract all the informations from Tables that contains a specific ip addresse , the first query give the name of tables , and the second one run through this table.

Comment: @Dipesh Can i display the results of the first query as a string ?

Comment: this way I can do a SELECT UNION